# In house networking – hub or switch?

Tags: networking, ethernet, home-networking, switch, hub

I have a 200 MBPS cable modem that has 4 Ethernet cables, but it is in one room, I want to go put a hub or switch in the attic and run Ethernet cables to each room in the house, two in the master bedroom, one in the living room and one in each of 3 bedrooms and one in the kitchen (maybe).

So, I will run one to the room where the modem is, and have that be the one that carries the internet to the hub or switch.

Then I'll go run all the cables through the house where I need them to go.

My question is, would a hub do?
or do I need a switch?

I've never done this before. My brother is in construction, he is going to come run the wall fish, to install the cables and run them to the central location, but I don't know what to plug them into, a hub or switch?

I looked at a switch and I don't see how it gets internet, the RJ45 cables all appear to go OUTBOUND, I don't see a place to plug the internet into.

So not sure what I'm doing.

Can you just tell me if I need a switch or if a hub will do?

I have 10 RJ45 wall outlets, and 1000 feet of Ethernet cable and the toolkit to make strip the wires and put them on the plugs.
and the tester to make sure they work.

I'd appreciate someone just letting me know if I need to use a switch or hub.
Also if you know of something I should be aware of, please point me in that direction.

Comment: Are you sure you have a real tester? They cost thousands of dollars, and you can get professional cable installation much cheaper. It's not like telephone wires, where simple electrical connectivity will work. There are many tests in the test suite.

Comment: I have one from Amazon, a Ethernet tool kit that came with a tester... seems to work fine. no idea how accurate it is. but it appears to be.

Comment: The primary tests are: Wire Map, Length, Insertion Loss, Near End Cross Talk (NEXT), Power Sum Near End Cross Talk (PSNEXT), Equal Level Far End Cross Talk (ELFEXT), Power Sum Equal Level Far End Crosstalk (PSELFEXT), Return Loss, Propagation Delay, and Delay Skew. If your tester does all that, then it is a proper tester. Most cost around $10,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hubs don't really exist anymore. They've been obsolete for ages.

Switches don't care what's connected to what port. They just ensure that all the connected devices can connect to each other. You can think of them as sending every packet they receive out every port but the one they received it on, with an optimization to avoid sending packets out ports they happen to know don't need to hear them.

Caution: Make absolutely certain you get the pins-to-pairs mapping correct. It is *not* sufficient just to ensure the pins-to-wires mappings is the same on both ends. Follow either [568A or 568B](https://www.computercablestore.com/tiaeia-568a-and-568b-wiring-color-codes) color codes.